# When to initialize the layout & theme specific details in Zend Framework?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, layout

I am new to ZF, so my question might look newbish and I apologize in advance if its already answered.

The sequence in which ZF execute a complete process is
1. routeStartup
2. process route
3. routeShutdown
4. dispatchLoopStartup
5. preDispatch
6. dispatch process starts
7. controller's init method
8. controller's helper's preDispatch
9. action's preDispatch
10. action
11. action's postDispatch
12. controller's helper's postDispatch
13. postDispatch
14. dispatchLoopShutdown

now there are multiple places where we can initiate + config layout & theme details. We can do it on stage 5, 7, 8 and 9. What stage is the best for this purpose.

The application will be using AJAX so if I load the layout details on stage 5, there are lots of chances that later I will be removing the layout and sending only XML response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best to configure your layout using the [application resource plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.layout) during bootstrap.

To disable layout whilst responding to XHR, use the [AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) action helper.

Edit: At what point do you know which theme you will use? If it's early enough and the required parameters are available, you could implement this using a bootstrap `_init*` method or custom layout app resource plugin.

Otherwise, I'd implement and register a controller action helper, setting the theme in its `preDispatch` override. Using the second method also gives you access to the request, therefore allowing you to make a decision based on the request method whether you bother with the layout or not. In fact, this might be a good candidate for a custom override of the AjaxContext helper itself.

Comment: Oh, 7 seconds before me and better answer :) +1

Comment: The application will be using different themes, so the bootstrap process won't know which theme to load/initiate. Though there will be a default theme, but the actual theme to load will be retrieved from the database under the user's personal settings. 2ndly if we initiate the loyout it bootstrap, and later cancel it, it means that initially we ran a code and later we won't need that which will be a performance penalty.

Comment: @Bryan I've updated my answer with some more ideas for you. Also, there's little overhead in configuring the layout although determining a theme would incur more work.

Comment: thanks Phil. I am using a plugin that uses the dispatchLoopStartup to check if user's access to the specific route. Once confirmed he has the access, I loads user's data which contains the theme related details. The reason to load user's data after checking the access is to avoid extra database calls in case user fail to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate and config layout before step 1 during Bootstrap - that's the best place :)